# hide out of stock variations in shortcode loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using [products attributes="someattr" terms="someterm"] shortcode to render a product loop. The issue here is that I want to be able to filter out the product if any of the variation is out of stock. 
The following does not achieve what I need:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'modifyshortcode', 10, 3);
function modifyshortcode( $query_args, $atts, $loop_name){

if($loop_name == 'products'){
        $query_args['meta_query'] = array( array(
            'key'     => '_stock_status',
            'value'   => 'outofstock',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ) );
        return $query_args;
}
```

The above does not filter out the products with 'outofstock' inventory status. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, can you check contains $loop_name ??
Could be this part is never entered.

Comment: Stock status also added as term to this taxonomy "product_visibility" .
So make tax_query to this taxonomy.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to go with a simpler woocommerce_product_is_visible filter solution, the following seems to be working for me in case someone needs a similar one:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible', 'hide_product_with_outofstock_variation', 10, 2 );
if(!function_exists('hide_product_with_outofstock_variation')){
    function hide_product_with_outofstock_variation( $is_visible, $id ) {

        $product = wc_get_product($id);
        $outofstock_term = get_term_by( 'name', 'outofstock', 'product_visibility' );
        $product_variations = $product->get_children();

        foreach ($product_variations as $variation) {

           // Get variation stock status
           $stock_status = get_post_meta($variation, '_stock_status');

           // if variant property 'outofstock' return false
           if(in_array($outofstock_term->name, $stock_status)){
            $is_visible = false;
           }
        }

        return $is_visible;
    }
}
```